# Drag and drop element text into textarea using angular CDK

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I want to drag list text into `textarea` I was able to implement this feature using jquery UI
[here is a code which is implemented with jquery UI](http://jsfiddle.net/3p1nra6m/1/)
However, I am working on an angular project which jquery UI is not part of it so I tried to achieve that using angular CDK drag and drop, however, I couldn't find any solution in the official drag drop document but I am new to angular so is there any way to achieve it with angular CDK drag and drop?

Comment: Rememebr that the cdkDropList are not only to use with list. So Just use two cdkDropList. One with the elements Draggables in a list, and another one empty with the text-area. The only is **not** use `transferArrayItem` you need use the function drop to give value to the textArea, some like "value=event.previousContainer.data"